# Laravel UUID as primary key and ID as foreign key

Tags: mysql, laravel

I've defined a `uuid` as primary key, and would like to use `id` (auto increment) as foreign key to define relationships.

Both Posts and Comments have in their migration:

```
$table->uuid('uuid')->primary();
$table->bigInteger('id');
```

Their models have:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'uuid';
protected $keyType = 'string';
public $incrementing = false;
```

And the comments migration has

```
$table->bigInteger('post_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
```

But if I run the migration I get `` General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `comments` add constraint `comments_post_id_foreign` foreign key (`post_id`) references `posts` (`id`) on delete cascade) `` of which I'm not sure why it's happening? Before adding the UUID logic it was working fine so I'm sure I've made a mistake there, but I'm not sure what as the error is generic.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a foreign key requires the referenced key and the foreign one to have the same type and sign. According to your migrations, both `posts.id` and `comments.id` are signed bigints but you are trying to add a foreign key to a *un*signed bigint.

In your migrations for `posts` and `comments`, change

```
$table->bigInteger('id');
```

to

```
$table->bigInteger('id')->unsigned();
```

and migrate them again.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

```
$table->foreignId('post_id')->constrained('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: Thanks, would be good to understand what this does exactly and how it's different from what I have.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$table->foreignUuid('post_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
```

You can have a look at the method which is inside the vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php

```
 /**
 * Create a new UUID column on the table with a foreign key constraint.
 *
 * @param  string  $column
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Schema\ForeignIdColumnDefinition
 */
public function foreignUuid($column)
{
    return $this->columns[] = new ForeignIdColumnDefinition($this, [
        'type' => 'uuid',
        'name' => $column,
    ]);
}
```